# How to filter records based on minimum date and some other criteria where each transaction can have multiple dates in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to extract transaction where quantity is -1 on very first date of the same transaction. Assume that single transaction have multiple rows.

We have following table

```
tXid_ID     Date        Qty
---------------------------------------
1       1/2/2014    -1
2       2/3/2014    1
2       3/3/2014    1
3       4/3/2014    1
4       5/3/2014    -1
4       6/3/2014    1
5       7/3/2014    -1
5       8/3/2014    1
6       9/3/2014    1
7       10/3/2014   1
7       11/3/2014   -1
----------------------------------
```

All I want to extract only those transactions which do not have quantity -1 on its first entry within same transaction ID.

Expected results should be like this

```
tXid_ID     Date        Qty
---------------------------------------
2       2/3/2014    1
2       3/3/2014    1
3       4/3/2014    1
6       9/3/2014    1
7       10/3/2014   1
7       11/3/2014   -1
----------------------------------
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Why do you have 7 in the desired results but not 4?

Comment: Because the first transaction of 4 have -1 Quantity and first transaction of 7 have 1 quantity.

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" transaction unless a column specifies the ordering.  You have not shown any such column.

Comment: I forgot to change the dates, Same taxid_ID have different dates. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below using subquery

```
 select a.* from table_name a
 where tax_id not in (  select tax_id from table_name t1
    where t1.date= (select min(date) from 
                table_name t2 where t1.tax_id=t2.tax_id
               ) and  t1.qty=-1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I was trying almost the same solution but unable to refer outer table inside sub-query.

Comment: Didn't work for me! as i mentioned subquery isn't referring outer table

Answer (score 0):

this one should work

```
select
  *
from
  tbl
where
  tXid_ID in (
    select
      t.tXid_ID
    from
      tbl t
      inner join (
        select
          min(date) as minDate,
          tXid_ID
        from
          tbl
        group by
          tXid_ID
      ) t1 on t1.minDate = t.date
    where
      t.Qty != -1
  )
```

Comment: This does not work either . Different Transactions can have same min(date) but different quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is aggregation:

```
select txid_id
from t
group by txid_id
having min(date) = min(case when qty = -1 then date end);
```

The `having` clause simply says that the minimum date is the minimum of the date where `qty = -1`.